# Excel Formula to Adjust Remaining Budget Evenly for Each Remaining Days

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Need your help for the formula that can adjust remaining amount evenly.

I need to use a formula that will adjust remaining amount of budget plan based on remaining days.

From this case, Since the remaining budget is 10  and remaining days are 5, Hence I need to add this remaining 10 of budget into 5 remaining days, meaning each remaining days' budget will be plus by 2 evenly.

Will someone help me what formula should I exactly use for each cells from H6 to H10 ?

Appreciate it and thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula in H4 will test if G4 is "done".  If it is then it returns E4 with " done)".  If G4 is not "done", then it sums E4 plus the unspent amount divided by remaining days.

```
=IF(G4="done",E4&" (done)",SUM(D4,SUM($F$4:$F$10)/SUM($G$4:$G$10)))
```

Comment: It's working, but how you get total of Column H ?

Comment: @rajesh substitute the word " (done)" into blank one.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler more robust formula (entered in `H4`) is:

```dart
=IF(ISTEXT(G4),E4&" ("&G4&")",D4+$F$11/$G$11)
```

It will allow the word "done" to be replaced with any text value while still continuing to work.

The formula also reuses the existing totals values, rather than recalculating them.